# Can You Deploy the Oslo Layout via Script Editor?

Tags: layouts, oslo, script-editor-webpart

I've created a few SharePoint sites in the 'Oslo' layout that look really nice. Every night, my company runs something through the system so that every SharePoint site reverts back to their ugly, custom layout. It takes a few clicks every morning to go back to Oslo through the front-end, but is there a way to make the Oslo layout permanent in the Script Editor? Whatever I hard enter in the Script Editor seems to stay...

Answer (score 1):

Well, any change you make is "permanent" until it's undone by somebody else - an automated job in this case.

So here's a possibly nefarious suggestion for you. If you can code, write an automated job of your own: Azure Function, PnP PowerShell running a scheduled job from a computer somewhere, maybe a Flow - that undoes whatever changes the system is making. It sounds like a master page flip if I understand this correctly. Make sure your job runs *after* the other job, and when you come in each morning your changes will be intact.

There's also the fact that your company has done work to enforce a standard and you are deliberately circumventing that. If there are repercussions to doing that, those are yours to deal with.